# Using uncrustify without aligning under open parenthesis

Tags: uncrustify

I'm trying to configure uncrustify (a source code beautifier) to
avoid aligning beneath a previous open parenthesis.  For
example, I'd like the code to look like this (from file
`indent_paren.c`):

```
void f(void)
{
    while (one &&
        two)
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

When I run uncrustify on the above code, the line `two)`
indents to align with the `(` from the line above:

```
void f(void)
{
    while (one &&
           two)
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

I'm using the latest version of uncrustify (0.59) compiled from
source, with the following configuration settings for this test
(in file `indent_paren.cfg`):

```
indent_with_tabs = 0
indent_columns   = 4
indent_paren_nl  = false
indent_bool_paren = false
```

I'm invoking uncrustify as follows:

```
uncrustify -c indent_paren.cfg indent_paren.c
```

I found the same behavior with version 0.56 (installed from the
repository for Ubuntu 11.04).  Am I using the wrong configuration
settings, or is something else wrong here?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After further experimentation and spelunking in the uncrustify
source code, I've found that the `indent_continue` option does
mostly what I want.  By default, `indent_continue` is zero, and
continued lines are indented to up beneath open parenthesis in
the line above.  Setting `indent_continue` to a non-zero value
overrides this behavior, causing continuation lines to be
indented based on the current "level".  So my original example
is indented as desired when using the following settings in
uncrustify.cfg:

```
indent_with_tabs = 0
indent_columns   = 4
indent_continue  = 4
```

Because the "level" is incremented for nested parentheses,
however, there is more indentation than desired for cases such
as:

```
void g(void)
{
    /* Nested parentheses cause undesired additional indent. */
    TRACE(("The varargs need extra parentheses %d %d\n",
        (firstArgIsLong + 
        withMultipleTerms),
        secondArg));
}
```

The above settings generate indentation as follows, with
undesired extra levels of indentation:

```
void g(void)
{
    /* Nested parentheses cause undesired additional indent. */
    TRACE(("The varargs need extra parentheses %d %d\n",
            (firstArgIsLong +
                withMultipleTerms),
            secondArg));
}
```

Looking at the uncrustify source, it appears that this behavior
is not adjustable.  `indent_continue` gives the desired results
in most cases, and it seems to be the closest that uncrustify
can come at this time.